# Can volume be interpreted as density $\times$ volume?

Tags: mass, volume

[In this optimization presentation](https://lpoo.github.io/assets/apresentacoes/thadeu.26.10.2012.pdf) there's a "volume constraint":

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n_{el}} v_i p_i \le V^*$$

where $v_i$ is the volume of a node element and $p_i$ is its density.

But because $density \times volume = mass$, but in the above it's a volume constraint, then does mass have some kind of volumetric interpretation here?

Comment: In the link you provide, they define what they mean by "density" in their context, which is an adimensional variable with no relation to the mass per volume density.

Comment: This is not a question about physics, it concerns mathematics.

Answer (score 0):

No, volume can not be interpreted as volume $\times$ (mass-)density.

Volume has a unit of $length^3$ and (mass-)density has a unit of $mass/length^3$.

However, density can be a lot more than just mass per volume. Current density is often measured as current per area, particle density (or number density according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_(disambiguation))) is usually particles per volume, charge density is electrical charge per volume.
In optics, the optical density of an element refers to how many orders of magnitude the element reduces the intensity of transmitted light.

So density is in most cases some quantity per length/area/volume, but some cases do not even satisfy this condition. And thats just the density part.

Neither could i find a clear statement what density/volumes they use in the linked presentation nor am i familiar enough with the topic to even guess. Maybe they use some "volume element / volume" density, which could easily satisfy the condition. Maybe the v and V are not both volumes in the sense of $m^3$. Or maybe they just use some fancy mathematical trick i am not aware of, that produces the right result without beeing "physically correct".

Comment: Based on other naming conventions I've seen, the small versions of uppercase units are often used to represent a quantity per unit mass.  I'm not sure what any of it would represent in context, but then that would make V* a dimensionless constant, specifically some type of volume type measurement (I've also seen the * nomenclature used to denote that).